# Strange fringe pattern on long exposure photo

Tags: lens, long-exposure, artifacts

While compositing a series of long exposure images, I noticed this strange fringe-like pattern getting brighter at each layer blended in "lighten" mode. It features a circle and a cross in the middle and those deformed lines around it, sightly brighter than the rest of the image. It looks like a lens issue, but I've shot some sky photos with it before, [like this one shot on the same location](https://www.flickr.com/photos/142025359@N07/27706223319/sizes/l/), so I think a badly placed light source could be the cause of this effect.

Lens: Vivitar 28-210mm F3.5-5.6 AF Zoom

Camera: Canon t5i

Shot at 28mm F3.5, 20 images of 30s each, raw, no camera denoise.

Is there a way to remove such pattern? Is it something common in this kind of setup?

[image: Photo]

Comment: do you see same pattern during day? do you see same pattern with shorter exposure? do you use any filters in front of the lens?

Comment: @aaaaaa no, I've never seen such a thing. again, I took the other referred image on the same night and couldn't find such pattern. I was using a UV filter.

Comment: Speculation: An interference pattern, like Newton’s rings, from some layer of the sensor assembly, made visible by monochromatic light in the night sky (e.g. sodium light pollution or oxygen airglow lines).

Comment: The perfect geometric pattern leads me to believe this is algorithm-induced moiré, rather than phyiscally-induced interference. I think we've seen something like this before. Did you use any lens profile correction in your processing (such as in Lightroom)?

Comment: Related, very similar: [What causes and how can I avoid this moiré pattern in a composite night sky photograph?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/45655)

Comment: Found it. Here's the one where a moiré was introduced by LR lens profile correction: [Night Photography Moire - Nikon D810](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/83463)

Comment: I'm very thankful, @scottbb. I was using lens profile correction in Rawstudio when converting the raw to jpeg. solved.